# Retrieving a random document from Amazon DocumentDB using $sample

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation, aws-documentdb

To support an application feature I need to retrieve a single document from a collection in an Amazon DocumentDB, and it would not be appropriate to retrieve the same document every time.

The [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) states that the $sample aggregation stage can be used to select a number of documents using a pseudorandom cursor. I've tried this on a local MongoDB instance and it does return a randomly selected document which is what I need.

```
db.benchmark.aggregate([
    { $sample: { size: 1}}
])
```

However when I try to use this same query on Amazon DocumentDB, instead of returning a random record, it consistantly returns the first record in the collection. This doesn't seem very useful as it's the same functionality as limit. The [Amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline) indicates that DocumentDB supports the $sample stage, but gives no further information on its implementation.

Is there a way to get DocumentDB to select a random record using the $sample aggregation stage operator?

Example:

```
db.temp.insertMany([
    { "_id": 1, "temperature" : 97.5, "humidity": 0.61, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 2, "temperature" : 97.2, "humidity": 0.60, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 3, "temperature" : 97.4, "humidity": 0.61, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 4, "temperature" : 97.9, "humidity": 0.61, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 5, "temperature" : 97.6, "humidity": 0.61, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 6, "temperature" : 97.5, "humidity": 0.62, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 7, "temperature" : 97.2, "humidity": 0.62, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 8, "temperature" : 97.1, "humidity": 0.63, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 9, "temperature" : 96.9, "humidity": 0.62, "timestamp" : new Date() },
    { "_id": 10, "temperature" : 97.4, "humidity": 0.63, "timestamp" : new Date()}
])

db.temp.aggregate(
    [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
    )
db.temp.aggregate(
    [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
    )
```

MongoDB 4.4.3 on Windows

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "humidity": 0.61,
    "temperature": 97.4,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2021-04-13T22:00:09.361Z"}
  }
]

[
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "humidity": 0.63,
    "temperature": 97.1,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2021-04-13T22:00:09.361Z"}
  }
]
```

DocumentDB 4.0.0

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "humidity": 0.61,
    "temperature": 97.5,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2021-04-13T22:00:45.628Z"}
  }
]

[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "humidity": 0.61,
    "temperature": 97.5,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2021-04-13T22:00:45.628Z"}
  }
]
```

Comment: As per their blog from 2019 it seems to work as expected with [$sample](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-new-aggregation-pipeline-capabilities-in-amazon-documentdb-to-build-powerful-aggregation-queries/#aws-comment-trigger-6727:~:text=3.%20Sample) . Can you provide some more context on the total documents in `benchmark`?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nagaraj. That confirms that DocumentDB's $sample is intended to return random documents. Now just need to figure out why it doesn't on my instance. Is there a console configuration option? An adminCommand? (Change streams need to be specifically enabled on DocumentDB via an adminCommand). Perhaps it's a bug in version 4.0.0.

Comment: I have added commands to reproduce.

Comment: By the looks of it, it seems a bug. Could you check with the previous version of the DocumentDB?

Comment: I just spun up a 3.6 cluster and tested on that: same result.

Comment: I think the best bet is to raise a support ticket for AWS. They might provide more inputs if there is a bug from their end.

Comment: DocumentDB is built ground up on a cloud native architecture with decoupled compute and storage, and thus uses a different engine than MongoDB under the hood. What's happening is that you likely have a small number of documents because of which $sample is returning the first document it finds. As you add more documents $sample should be able to pick a random document.

Comment: @meet-bhagdev I tried executng the example insert statement repeatedly and eventually the query started returning one of what appeared to be a restricted set of id's. Not randomly selected, with 500 documents i'd see the ids 1, 55, 113, 151, 255, 287, 403 over and over again. I'd don't understand this behaviour and i wouldn't say the semantics are 'compatible' with MongoDB, but if the implementation dependes critically on the number of documents that does answer the question. If you write out your comment as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a random set of records will not work with the $sample operator in DocumentDB in the same way that it does in MongoDB.

DocumentDB's current implementation will only select a contiguous series of records starting from a record randomly selected from within a static subset of the collection. The size of the static subset is related to the size of the overall collection, and may be linked to the way that the records are grouped on disk. For a small enough collection (approximatly < 50 records) the static subset may only contain one point, and a query using the $sample operator will return the same series of records every time.

To get compatible behaviour between MongoDB and DocumentDB use a pipeline combining skip and limit:

```
db.temp.aggregate([ 
  { 
    $skip : db.temp.countDocuments() * Math.random() 
  }, 
  { 
    $limit: 1
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating your own logic here.

1. If the number of rows in DynamoDB fixed, then use it. else fetch the number of rows every 5 mins or every 100th (or 1000th) call to the DB.
2. Select a random number from the count using a random number generator.
3. fetch that particular row from DB :)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, but I was specifically interested in using the $sample operator. I realise that i could write a function to emulate $sample - but i need to avoid making my implementation dependant on the implementation of to NoSQL engine, as it may run against MongoDB or DocumentDB depending on where it is deployed.

Comment: For the record I'd prefer an implementation like: 


db.temp.aggregate([
    { $skip : db.temp.countDocuments() * Math.random() },
    { $limit: 1}
]);

An asynchronous count would have the flaw that it may attempt to query a record that no longer exists if the collection is reduced in size between the count and the query.

Comment: I Agree with that @RichardWoods. Will get back If I find something :)